# SQL selecting rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:
1 - Person, 2 - Address

Each person can have multiple Address entries.
Both tables have a status column.

- If all Address rows status column are 'canceled', the status value for Person entry will be 'canceled'.
- If all rows in the Address table are 'completed', then the status value for Person will be 'completed'.
- If one of the Address table rows are canceled, and the
  rest are 'completed', the Person status will be 'completed'.
- If one of the Address rows are still 'inprogress', then Person status will be
  'inprogress'

I want to select all personID in the Person table where all rows for that person in the Address table do not have an 'inprogress' status, but have their Person.Status = 'inprogress'

I'm trying to do that by doing the ff.

```
select personID
from Person P
where P.status not in ('completed','canceled') and
      P.personID in (
           select A.personID 
           from Address A
           where A.status in ('completed','canceled') 
           and A.personID = P.personID 
           group by personID
      )
```

Im just not sure if its correct since I might be selecting personIDs which have the canceled and completed but might still have in progress address rows.

Comment: I'd usually say that the sub-query's `GROUP BY` can be removed. Perhaps SQL Server want it, or SELECT DISTINCT, to perform better?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: You just changed your requirements and invalidated the answers given below.  Do you want to compute a status using a query, or select what is already there?

Comment: select what is already there. I just dont want to miss any Address rows for a specific Person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT personID
FROM Person p
WHERE p.status = 'inprogress'
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Address a 
    WHERE a.personId = p.personId 
)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Address a 
    WHERE a.personId = p.personId 
    AND a.status = 'inprogress'
)
```

This will return all persons with the status `'inprogress'` that have at least one record in the Address table, but doesn't have addresses with status `'inprogress'`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to select all personID in the Person table where all rows for
>   that person in the Address table do not have an 'inprogress' status,
>   but have their Person.Status = 'inprogress'

Based on your key requirement as above, I hope this should be fine...

```
select personID from Person
where status = 'inprogress'and personID in
(select personID from Address
where status in ('completed','canceled') group by personID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Person.PersonID
from Person
join address on Person.PersonID = address.personID and Person.status='inprogress'
group by Person.PersonID 
having count(case when address.status='inprogress' then 1 else null end)=0
```

count function doesn't count nulls, so if count result == 0 then there are no status = 'inprogress' for current PersonID